# Error after upgrading to joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade, error-reporting

Whilst trying to upgrade to Joomla 3.3, I get the following error:

```
1146 - An error has occurred.

Table smilyo_skc.xv36g_postinstall_messages doesn't exist SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM xv36g_postinstall_messages
```

Return to Control Panel

```
Call stack

#       Function        Location    
1       JApplicationCms->execute()      /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/administrator/index.php:42   
2       JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()      /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:251    
3       JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()       /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:159  
4       JComponentHelper::renderComponent()     /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:98   
5       JComponentHelper::executeComponent()        /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:332   
6       require_once()      /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:352   
7       JControllerLegacy->execute()        /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/administrator/components/com_cpanel/cpanel.php:15    
8       JControllerLegacy->display()        /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php:730   
9       CpanelViewCpanel->display()     /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php:693   
10      FOFModel->getItemList()     /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/administrator/components/com_cpanel/views/cpanel/view.html.php:59    
11      PostinstallModelMessages->buildQuery()      /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/fof/model/model.php:1152   
12      FOFModel->buildQuery()      /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/administrator/components/com_postinstall/models/messages.php:32  
13      FOFUtilsObservableDispatcher->trigger()     /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/fof/model/model.php:2033   
14      FOFUtilsObservableEvent->update()       /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/fof/utils/observable/dispatcher.php:146    
15      call_user_func_array()      /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/fof/utils/observable/event.php:63  
16      FOFModelBehaviorFilters->onAfterBuildQuery()            
17      FOFModel->getTableFields()      /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/fof/model/behavior/filters.php:35  
18      JDatabaseDriverMysqli->getTableColumns()        /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/fof/model/model.php:2049   
19      JDatabaseDriver->loadObjectList()       /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php:397  
20      JDatabaseDriverMysqli->execute()        /home/smilyo/public_html/skcca.com/libraries/joomla/database/driver.php:1281
```

Joomla! Debug Console Session Profile Information Memory Usage Database Queries

Comment: What version are you upgrading from?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to fix the database. Go to "Extensions Manager" -> choose "Database" in the sidebar menu -> click "Fix" button.